# Sorting and Alphabetizing String Inputs for Binary Tree

Tags: python, list, sorting, binary, alphabetical

I am having to create a guest list of 6 names based on a binary tree structure. 
The list needs to be alphabetized then sorted into 2 lists by names starting with letters A-L and M-Z.
However, when I run this code, it simply prints only 5 elements of my list in the order they were input under each category. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to programming, Python and stackoverflow, and have been assigned this for a course, and have spent over a week reviewing different materials but I'm just stuck. Thank you.

IDLE Python 3.6, I think I need to use some sort of sorting method or that there may be an error or missing component to my enterguest loops

```
class Node(object):                       
    def __ init __(self):   
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = list()


def enterguest(root, guest):    
    if guest < root.data[0]:
        if root.left == None:
            root.left = Node()
            root.left.data.append(guest)
        else:
            enterguest(root.left, guest)
    else:
        if guest > root.data[0]:
            if root.right == None:
                root.right = Node()
                root.right.data.append(guest)
            else:
                enterguest(root.right, guest)
        else:
            root.data.append(guest)


def guestresults(root):
    if root == None:
        return
    print(root.data)
    guestresults(root.left)
    guestresults(root.right)

root = Node()       
root.data.append("M")
for i in range (0, 6):
    enterguest(root, input("Enter guest name:"))
print("Guests A-L")
guestresults(root.left)
print("Guests M-Z")
guestresults(root.right)
```

I expect the output to be the 6 names alphabetized and separated into two lists based on the first letter of each name, one list being names A-L and the second list being names M-Z. The actual output is displaying the same 5 names in the order they were input under each category I have created.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code prints the subtree in pre-order (i.e. parent before children), while you should print in in-order (left child first, then parent, then right child).

So change:

```
print(root.data)
guestresults(root.left)
guestresults(root.right)
```

to:

```
guestresults(root.left)
print(root.data)
guestresults(root.right)
```

The other issue occurs when you enter "M" as a name: in that case it is appended to the root data, which you never output.

I would avoid this kind of problems by not storing equal strings in the same node. When you have an equality, just go to the right child also. So change:

```
else:
    if guest > root.data[0]:
        if root.right == None:
            root.right = Node()
            root.right.data.append(guest)
        else:
            enterguest(root.right, guest)
    else:
        root.data.append(guest)
```

to:

```
else:
    if root.right == None:
        root.right = Node()
        root.right.data.append(guest)
    else:
        enterguest(root.right, guest)
```

With this change it will work. But please consider also the following points which would improve your solution:

- Now that you don't store multiple strings in one node any more, do not create the `data` property as a `list`.
- Let the `Node` constructor take an argument so that you can immediately set the `data` property upon construction.
- Instead of creating functions `enterguest` and `guestresults`, try to create those as *methods* of your class. This is more in line with an object-oriented approach.
- Instead of using `print` in those functions, consider *returning* the result as a list (or `yield` the results one by one). Leave the actual printing for the main program only. It is always good to separate (business) logic from the actual outputting code.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information and advice for better programming style. The fixes addressed my code issues completely.